# Identify real world elevation for digital elevation (DEM) GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, mosaic, gdal-merge

This seems like it should be simple, but I have been struggling to figure out the best way to identify the real world minimum and maximum elevations from a GeoTIFF I downloaded from the National Map. I collected a GeoTIFF that is a 1x1 degree 1/3 arc-sec, and the GeoTIFF has a Z (vertical) min and max value shown in the Layer's bar when I upload it to QGIS. However, I am skeptical that the Z values of the GeoTIFF correlate directly to vertical meters, and I suspect they are possibly relative, but relative to what? I don't know. For example, there are values from 1186 to 3407 in the GeoTIFF (min and max values), but I know that in the region, the a town in the area is about 4625 ft above sea level (1410m) but I don't believe there is a location that is 11177 ft above sea level in the 1x1 degree domain. I could be wrong here, but does anyone know an efficient way to extract the actual DEM elevations?

Metadata of the DEM:

```
Size is 21612, 32412
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["NAD83",
DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
CS[ellipsoidal,2],
AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
ORDER[1],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
ORDER[2],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
ID["EPSG",4269]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-108.000555556093445,36.000555556294785)
Pixel Size = (0.000092592592692,-0.000092592592692)

Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left (-108.0005556, 36.0005556) (108d 0' 2.00"W, 36d 0' 2.00"N)
Lower Left (-108.0005556, 32.9994444) (108d 0' 2.00"W, 32d59'58.00"N)
Upper Right (-105.9994444, 36.0005556) (105d59'58.00"W, 36d 0' 2.00"N)
Lower Right (-105.9994444, 32.9994444) (105d59'58.00"W, 32d59'58.00"N)
Center (-107.0000000, 34.5000000) (107d 0' 0.00"W, 34d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=21612x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
Computed Min/Max=1185.740,3444.489
Minimum=1185.740, Maximum=3444.489, Mean=1905.893, StdDev=340.599
Metadata:
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=3444.4892578125
STATISTICS_MEAN=1905.8925270605
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1185.7398681641
STATISTICS_STDDEV=340.59880046937
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Comment: What does the metadata say?

Comment: You question is unclear, but if you want to get the elevation for a set of points, you can use the point sampling tool in qgis.  If you want something else, you should clarify your question.

Comment: Clarification follow up to Ian's question: What does the external meta data/information of the National Map, your data source, say about the units of the pixel cells? That information is not included in your file's embedded metadata.

Comment: Building on to the comments above, you mention 11 177ft in your question randomly. Where did that number come from? From the meta data it looks like the lowest elevation is 1185(m?) and 3444(m?). As bugmenot mentioned, you may need to check the information from the site you downloaded the file from to see how this dataset was derived.

Comment: I read the metadata to show that the units are in meters, with the min/max values as 1185/3444 (meters).

Comment: So the 11177 came from a conversion from meters (3407) to ft from a max I got from a DEM. Sorry, I haven't been consistent with numbers since I'm playing with 6 individual 1x1 GeoTiff's. I created a mosaic of several of them. Here is the metadata for one of those GeoTiff's from the National Map
https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/60de9d94d34e3a6dca2a8fd2
It looks like according to that page, all measurements are in meters, so I guess there really is measured elevation change of over 2259 m in the domain. With that said, do I take the 1185 as an above sea level estimate?

Comment: USGS 3DEP surface models reference decimeters above the North American Vertical Datum of 1988 (NAVD88).